# Objective-C: Loading animation on UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiimageview

I'm trying to use UIImageView as an animation when my UIWebView is loading, and remove that view when it's finished loading. However, I'm unable to make it start/stop animating when webview starts and stops loading. Code snippets:

```
@synthesize webView; //UIWebView
@synthesize loadView; //UIImageView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...

    loadView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];
    [loadView setAnimationImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                                    nil]];
    [loadView setTag:1];
    [loadView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [loadView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    [self.view addSubview:loadView];

    [webView loadRequest:request]; //request is defined somewhere else
}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)curWebView {
    [loadView startAnimating];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)curWebView {  
    [loadView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)curWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [loadView stopAnimating];
    // ... Code to show reload button
}
```

If I call `[loadView startAnimating]` in `viewDidLoad`, it animates, but `[loadView stopAnimating]` in `webView:didFailLoadWithError` still wouldn't work. Otherwise, laodView only shows a blank white screen.

Comment: Can you verify that `webViewDidStartLoad:` is getting called? Also, are you sure you want to remove the view when it finishes loading the webView -- is this controller used only once and discarded?

Comment: @BenFlynn Yes, I added `NSLog`s everywhere to make sure all methods are getting called. For some reason, `[loadView startAnimating]` and `[loadView stopAnimating]` don't do anything, even though the rest of the code in the methods are getting called. And yes, I want loadView to be used only once (at the beginning of my app).

Comment: Hmm, because the web view would be loading asynchronously, I wonder if those methods are called on a thread other than main? Can you try logging the [NSThread currentThread]? You may need to dispatch the animation explicitly on the main queue.

Comment: `viewDidAppear:` seems like a better place to call it, but do try calling cancel explicitly on the main thread (all UI stuff has to be run on it).

Comment: @BenFlynn they are all in the same thread. I'll try `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Hmm, I'm running out of ideas then, though maybe I'll give it a try later. If you are just showing a spinner, you could look at using a UIActivityIndicatorView, though you could easily hit the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a local webpage with the spinner in it (animated gif?), loading that and setting it running, then while it's animating, load your remote page in the back.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol in interface. Have you set `delegate` of `UIWebView` in `XiB` file.